# Explain htaccess rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have made this .htaccess file over the last hour through searching, copy and pasting etc.

It does work how I want it to.

However I do not understand it.

Could someone please put it down step by step what is happening here in layman's terms for me.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

And if there are any tips please throw them in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

`^www\.example\.com$` The anchors `^$` mean this is the complete string in `HTTP_HOST`, nothing before or after. Therefore, if the domain name passed with the request matches `www.example.com` *exactly*, the entire URI `(.*)` is redirected to `example.com`, thereby stripping off the `www.` from the front.

---

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

A `-f` flag to `RewriteCond` tests if the first argument is a file that actually exists. In this case, it tests for the value of `REQUEST_FILENAME`, which would be the last part (`file`) of a URI like `example.com/directory/file` exists as a PHP file, by adding a `.php` extension onto the tested argument.

So, if `file.php` actually exists, the request for the non-existent `file` is here rewritten silently into its corresponding PHP file with `$1.php`.  So if `/directory/notexists` did not have a corresponding `directory/notexists.php` file, it would *not* be rewritten.

---

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

`THE_REQUEST` contains the complete `GET/POST` request the browser originally sent, like `GET /index.php`.  So what has been matched here is similar to the previous block.

- `^[A-Z]{3,9}` first matches the verb `GET` or `POST`, etc. but doesn't capture it for reuse
- the `/([^\ ]+)` then captures everything following `/` and up to the next whitespace, like the `index` in `GET /index.php`.
- The `\.php` is literally matched

Ok, then the following `RewriteRule` takes that `index` captured into `%1` with the above condition, and *actually redirects* the browser to remove the `.php` extension so the browser's ending URL looks like `/index`.

In other words, if the browser requests `/directory/file.php` with the `.php` extension, it redirects the user to `/directory/file` to strip off the `.php`.

---

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

And this one matches anything containing `/index` in the original request, but it need not be at the start of the URI. In other words, `/directory/index` would match, as would `/directory/subdir/index.php`.  No matter what it matches, it is redirected to whatever comes *before* the index part.  Let's break it down:

- `^(.*)` matches whatever comes at the start into `$1`
- `index.php` .. comes after whatever was matched above

That is then redirected just to the `$1` component, so a URL like `/directory/subdir/index.php` if directly requested by the browser, would be redirected to point to the cleaner URL: `/directory/subdir/` without the `index.php` appearing in the address bar.

Comment: A very well defined and informative answer, I now completely understand the code I am using and now feel like I can use it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Added in-line comments to your `.htaccess` code.

```
# If URL contains "www."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
# remove it for ALL request
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# If adding ".php" to the URL points to a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
# Serve the PHP file
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

# If a URL request contains ".php"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
# Redirect to the same URL but without ".php"
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# If the request points to index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
# Remove and redirect to "/"
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```