# Redirect to https but without .php

Tags: regex, https

Now I have a https. I need a redirection in the .htaccess. I could find this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But I find that if the user writes:

```
http://myDomain/someFile
```

It redirects to:

```
https://myDomain/someFile.php
```

I suppose that the correct should be without .php
How to do that?

Those are all the rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the working code for your problem. I have checked this on my server, and it is working fine

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#for https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Here is a link for explanation of the above code - [Explain htaccess rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236838/explain-htaccess-rules)

Comment: Can you explain your code, please? I do not understand

Comment: Have you tried this on your site?, just rename your current .htaccess file to .htaccess.bak and use this code by creating a new .htaccess file. It will definetly work.

Comment: It seems to work, but I need time to study it. This is complicated me. I will say something as soon as possible

Comment: As this answer solved your problem, I request you to mark this answer as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Why do I need that condition?: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php I see that if I do not use it it does not work but I do not understand what it does. It seems to me that the RewriteRule should be enough

Comment: haven't you read about the usage of that in the link I provided? In very simple words, it is redirecting to a file name which doesn't consist ".php", if you request https://example.com/index.php it redirects to https://example.com/index (here the server will show a file name "index").  if you request http://example.com/index it will show http://www.example.com/index

Comment: I have a question too, why haven't I got a bounty for this answer? Is there something you can do, to help me with this?

Comment: I thought that I only had to accept the answer. I read the instructions and I see that I had to click to the +50 icon too. I hope this solves the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142970/discussion-between-ankit-dixit-and-nrc).

Answer (score 0):

Have your .htaccess as this by turning `MultiViews` off. Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.php`.

You can also combine `www` and `http` rules into a single rule to avoid multiple `301` redirections.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: In the last line, why (.+?) and not just (.*)

Comment: `.*`  match 0 or more characters and adding `.php` in front of blank URI is not possible. Besides my rule also allows a trailing `/`

Comment: I deleted all I had in the .htaccess and only put your code and empty the cache. Then nothing works. No errors, just a blank page

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser for testing? Check in Chrome dev tool to see what response code did you get in browser?

Comment: the www and https works fine. The problem is with the .php If I do not put the .php I see nothing. Google console says Failed to load resource

Comment: That means last rule to add `.php` is failing. Your .htaccess must be located inside `DocumentRoot` and your `.php` files should also be in same directory.

Comment: this is how it is. Remember that the .htaccess works with the code that I provide in the question

Comment: Then it should work as well since last rule works for me on many live websites.

Comment: I believe if you comment out `Options -MultiViews` line then it will work again. But it will work not because of rewrite rule but due to ` content negotiation` and will expose `.php` URL to your client.

Answer (score 0):

If you use php then you probably have Apache. You should find your .conf file. I have it at

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf (Kubuntu 16.04.)
```

and change the virtual host settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    . . .

    Redirect "/" "https://your_domain_or_IP/"

    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I asked to my hosting provider and I do not have access to the .config. It seems that my only option is the .httaccess

Answer (score 0):

Give a shot to this in your ***.htaccess*** (at the root of your ***public_html***)

```
#FORCE HTTPS CONNECTION
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#FORCE HTTPS CONNECTION
```

Let me know if it worked out ;)

Comment: It does not work, the problem persists. Why do you think it should work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect http to https, use the following redirection code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Have you notice that your code is exactly the same  than mkseen?