# Understanding an old .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Could someone explain this RewriteCond to me?
Especially the HTTP/ portion at the end:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/ [R=301,L]
```

I found a very good explanation for the first half of the condition already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236838/explain-htaccess-rules), but I'm still confused with the "/index.php\ HTTP/" portion.

And again: Why the "HTTP/" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found a very good explanation for the first half of the condition already here, but I'm still confused with the "/index.php\ HTTP/" portion.

That explanation is omitting some detail. `THE_REQUEST` server variable contains the first line of the HTTP request headers. And will contain a string of the form:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
```

So, it contains 3 pieces of information, separated with *spaces*. You have the request method (GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, etc.), the URI and the protocol/version used (HTTP v1.1 in this case).

For this particular regex you don't necessarily need to include the final `HTTP/` part, just up to and including the *space*. However, by including `http/` it makes the regex easier to read and less prone to error. It would not be best practice to end on a *space* (that you can't see).

The following would be equivalent:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\s
```

This uses the shorthand character class for whitespace (`\s`) instead of escaping a literal *space* (so you can "see" the *space*).

Or, use double quotes to surround the argument:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} " /index\.php "
```

(Although, that almost looks like an error at first glance.)

The reason for including this *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) in the first place is to prevent a rewrite loop should you be rewriting the request to `index.php` later (a front-controller pattern). `THE_REQUEST` is not updated throughout the request (unlike other variables) when it is internally rewritten by Apache.

Comment: Awesome! The "hidden whitespace" would have boggled me for a while. Thanks!